# SSL websockets with Nginx cannot connect

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket

Having issues with getting `Nginx` to `proxy_pass` with websockets and SSL (WSS).

**NGINX Config**

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  ''      close;
}

server {
    server_name site.io www.site.io;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8989/graphql;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.site.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = site.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name site.io www.site.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Server Code**

```
const initApiServer = () => {
  try {
    const app = express();

    // Allow CORS
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
      next();
    });

    // Set security-related HTTPS headers
    app.use(helmet());

    // Setup for JSON and url encoded bodies
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.use('/', apiRouter); // Apply API routes
    const apollo = new ApolloServer({
      typeDefs,
      resolvers,
      context: { db },
      introspection: true, // enabled playground in prod
      playground: true, // enabled playground in prod
    });
    apollo.applyMiddleware({ app });

    const server = createServer(app);
    apollo.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

    server.listen(8989, () => {
      getLogger().info(`API served at ${Config.PROTOCOL}://${Config.HOSTNAME}:${Config.PORT_API}`);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    getLogger().error(`Error starting API Server: ${err.message}`);
    require('../server').exit('SIGTERM'); // eslint-disable-line
  }
};
```

I receive a variety of different errors:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.io:8989/ws' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.io:8989/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I have tested the server locally with non-SSL and it works fine. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.io:8989/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

This error message suggests that you try to access the websocket server with TLS (i.e. `wss://`) on port 8989.

> ```
>     proxy_pass         http://localhost:8989/graphql;
> ```

This part of the configurations suggests that on port 8989 the server is not expecting TLS, i.e. `ws://` should be used.

```
location /ws {
   ...
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
```

And this suggests that you've setup the TLS on port 443 (standard port). This means your access should be either for `ws://site.io:8989/graphql` to access the websocket directly and without TLS or for `wss://site:io/ws` (without port 8989, i.e. standard port 443) to access the websocket behind the nginx. It should not be `wss://site.io:8989/ws` as you've tried.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great now. I ended up changing the nginx to route to `https` and removing the port worked like a charm. Been banging my head on this one for a little. Much appreciated!

Comment: One quick thing to add that got me is I needed to add a trailing slash for mine.  `wss://foo.com/ws-link/`